# Where-Function in Acess

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a form, that populates a table named: Tasks

Tasks has columns: Name, and Date

I created an append query to append records from the Task table, to another table Called Task Progress, which has the same fields with some history.

For instance, Tasks will have the names: Ronaldo 1/1/2015.

And Task Progress will have Ronaldo's name show up multiple times for each task he's completed historically.

The problem is, that every time run the query it appends all the records in the task table, which creates duplicates.

I'm pretty sure I need to use a Where function in the criteria, but having problem figuring out how to write the Where function, so it only appends new records to the Task Progress Table.

Tips?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: Please display the SQL of the append query, so we have better understanding of what you are doing, and where could the mistake be